# How to get the text name of selected dropdown value

Tags: typescript, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

How to get the text name of selected dropdown value.

Using a prime ng dropdown

**HTML**

```
   <p-dropdown [options]="regionSelectList" [(ngModel)]="reg" [filter]="true" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">  </p-dropdown>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRecipient(reg);">Add</button>
```

**TS**

```
addRecipient(reg: any){
    console.log(reg) //which return code not text.
}
```

How can I get the text or label also with code ?

Answer (score 1):

How do you populate `regionSelectList` ?

If it looks like

`this.regionSelectList = [{label:'Region A', value:'regionA'}, {label:'Region B', value:'regionB'}];`

it should be ok : you'll get the `value` property in your `addRecipient` method.

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1l5vezdfYQl35FkRKrQq?p=preview)

Comment: Is there any way to get the label value in the onChange event ?

Comment: Yes, try with `event.value`.

Comment: event.value only gives the value. since the options is like [ { label: 'lable1', value:'value1'}]. It only gives the value. I need to read label.

Comment: Find the right object in the options array by the value. Then, you'll have access to the label.

Comment: I have two similiar value ( 7,7) when i search like that, it only returns the first occurrence of the value. Thats why I am asking

Comment: You should not have similar values in your dropdown. How your user knows which one he has to select ??

Comment: The use case is , for both label the value is same. Thats only I put same value inside that.